# Can't Install Package System.Net.Http from Nuget

Tags: c#, android, http, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I cannot install the package `System.Net.Http` I tried updating my Nuget but still same error occur by the way i'm  using `Visual Studio 2015 Community`  developing my android application

This is the error:

> Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently you are not going to be able to use System.Net.Http 4.0.0 even if you managed to install it into a Xamarin Android project since Xamarin does not fully support the new .NET Core NuGet packages, such as System.Net.Http. So you should look at using another NuGet package.

You could try the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package instead which includes assemblies for Xamarin Android projects.

Comment: Thank Very much works for me using the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet